# Clickable i class icon HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an i class icon that isn't clickable. The icon is for a table so when you click on the the arrow the table will be sorted after that criteria.

However the arrow isn't clickable and I can't get it to work. Some HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="table" id="col-0">Name <i class="right"></i></th>
        <th class="table" id="col-1">Tests <i class="right"></i></th>
        <th class="table" id="col-2">Killed <i class="right"></i></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Where the i class is not clickable. The entire th is clickable except for the i class. Why isn't the on click event inherited down?

```
i {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

JS where the onclick is added

```
    for (var i = 0; i < theads.length; i++) {
        theads[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {sortable_table_onclick(e);});
    }
```

Comment: You haven't defined `theads` in your code. You should provide a real [mcve].

Comment: `<i>` elements are designed to make text italic. If you want something to click on, use a `<button>`.  A button will be focusable for keyboard navigation and screen readers will announce it as being interactive.

Comment: add the property css -  {pointer-events : none}  to these .right (elements)